# Multiple-selection drop down list in an MS Access 2013 form

Tags: database, vba, ms-access, user-interface

I'd like to use a drop-down multi-select control on an MS Access 2013 form (the selection could be done using multiple checkboxes, but it's optional).

I would very much like to avoid modifying the source tables, so adding multivalued lookup fields are currently out of the question for me.

Actually, I could use any kind of drop-down multi-select control (not necessarily with check boxes), list or combo box, but unfortunately Access provides only listbox (it's unclear how to make it into a dropdown list) and non-multiselect combobox.

Does anyone know how to work around these limitations?

Thanks!

**Edit:**
This is an example of how such a control could look:

[image: Multi-select dropdown list]

It was taken from an Access table, the idea is to use it on a form.